# Django Model form is showing invalid with initialized values and file

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-file-upload

I have a **model** like this:

```
class Cohortpdfs(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,editable=True)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=200,validators=[MaxLengthValidator(100)])
    content=models.FileField()
    cohort_id=models.ForeignKey(Cohort,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=0,db_constraint=False)
```

I want to initialize and save data from views.

**views.py:**

```
    if requests.method == 'POST':  
        initialvalue={
            'cohort_id':id,
            'title':requests.POST.get('title'),
            'content':requests.FILES['content'],
        }
              
        if contentform.is_valid():     
            print("form valid")
        else:
            print("FORM ERROR")
```

**Forms.py**

```
class CohortpdfsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Cohortpdfs

        fields = [
            "title","content","cohort_id",
        ]

        widgets={
            'title' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','max_length':20}),
            'content': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'cohort_id': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'hidden'}),
        }
```

This is showing my form is not valid. How can I initialize the form with the uploaded file(PDF) and save it into the model database?

Comment: When form is invalid, it has a dictionary with errors in `form.errors`. What errors does your form have?

Comment: its blank. forms.error shows nothing.

Comment: That is weird, because `is_valid` returns `True` if the form is bound (i.e. it was passed data to) and if there are no errors - https://github.com/django/django/blob/439cd73c1670a2af25837149a68526fe5555399d/django/forms/forms.py#L205 Make sure that you pass request data to the form when initializing. It should look like this - `contentform = CohortpdfsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`. Related django docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form